# What does return(char)((((ch + key) - offset) % 26) + offset) code do?

Tags: c#, char, caesar-cipher

So I was looking up C# Caesar ciphers online and I found this website:
https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/caesar-cipher

I looked through and generally the code made sense to me until this part:

```
char offset = char.IsUpper(ch) ? 'A' : 'a';
return (char)((((ch + key) - offset) % 26) + offset);
```

I understand the ternary operator, it's mainly the second line that I can't make sense of, it returns a character,but somehow adds a character and a number together, subtracts a character, gets the modulus and then adds on a character?

The only explanation I've come up with is that each character has an ID and it's doing the operations on that rather than the character itself?
 Honestly it's a bit beyond me, if someone could explain it that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a key pressed, say it was F, the ASCII code will be 0x46
thus:

```
int ch = 0x46;
```

then the value is shifted by the `key` parameter (let's take 3)

```
int key = 21;
```

the `offset` is just the offset between the numerical vaue and the ASCII code:

```
'A' - 'A' = 0 -> A is at index 0 of letters
'B' - 'A' = 1 -> B is at index 1 of letters
...
'Z' - 'A' = 25 -> Z is at index 25
```

same thing when letters are lowercase, using 'a'.

now the `% 26` performs some round robin on letters

thus `(('F' + 21) -'A') % 26` gives 0

then coming back in the letters range:
0 + 'A' = 'A'

As described in your title, this is just a Caesar cypher in C.

Comment: Oh okay, so it is simply just working with the IDs rather than the letter itself, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

According to [ECMA-334 (C# language spec)](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf):

> The `char` type is used to represent Unicode code units. A variable of type char represents a single 16-bit Unicode code unit.

According to [the unicode.org glossary](http://unicode.org/glossary/)<sup>*</sup>:

> Code Unit. The minimal bit combination that can represent a unit of encoded text for processing or interchange. The Unicode Standard uses 8-bit code units in the UTF-8 encoding form, 16-bit code units in the UTF-16 encoding form, and 32-bit code units in the UTF-32 encoding form.

From these two resources we can infer that the `char` type is a 16-bit wide field of binary digits. What better way to implement a 16-bit wide field of binary digits than as a 16-bit integer, hmmmm?